# How to wait for Akka actor to start during tests?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a test that needs to make an assertion on something that happens during an actor's `preStart()`, but I haven't figured out how to wait until that happens, and sometimes it doesn't happen before the assertion is made (and sometimes it does). I have tried this:

```
EventFilter.debug(start = "started", occurrences = 1).assertDone(10.seconds)
```

but I get an error message when using it:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 1 messages outstanding on DebugFilter(None,Left(started),false)
```

Comment: Have you tried `eventually`? (http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html)

Comment: @amorfis I'm not using Scalatest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the creation of the actor inside an [`intercept`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/testkit/EventFilter.html#intercept[T](code:=%3ET)(implicitsystem:akka.actor.ActorSystem):T) block:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.testkit.EventFilter
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    log.debug("started MyActor...")
  }

  def receive = {
    case m => log.debug(s"Received this message: $m")
  }
}

object MyActor {
  def props() = Props[MyActor]
}

object EventFilterTest extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("testsystem", ConfigFactory.parseString("""
    akka.loggers = ["akka.testkit.TestEventListener"]
    akka.loglevel = "DEBUG"
  """))

  EventFilter.debug(start = "started", occurrences = 1) intercept {
    val myActor = system.actorOf(MyActor.props)
    myActor ! "cows"
  }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
[DEBUG] [...] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://testsystem)] logger log1-TestEventListener started
[DEBUG] [...] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://testsystem)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [...] [testsystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://testsystem/user/$a] Received this message: cows
```

The intercept "catches" the debug statement in the actor's `preStart` hook.

Comment: Using `intercept` works, but only if I have `akka.actor.debug.lifecycle=on` as well. Which I was expecting -- I had all that stuff already -- but it's strange that your code works (I haven't tested it) without that.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: It didn't occur to me to set `akka.actor.debug.lifecycle=on`. My code works without that setting because there's a `log.debug("started MyActor...")` statement inside `preStart()`.